# How should I construct a secure redirect_uri?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I have read a number of questions on the underlying necessity of a `redirect_uri`. I don't want to screw this up! Can anyone give an example of how a secure `redirect_uri` could be constructed? For example,

`mysite.co/securepage.php.....`

Other than a page somewhere that is obscure, is there something that must be in the page to validate a client request..

Many thanks.

UPDATE: This is all intended to incorporate a service (Uber) into my app. This is their authentication page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: after clarifications added to the question following comments, the "redirect" part is actually [part of oAuth](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-two-receive-redirect) in the provider's API and not related to the OWASP section I initially pointed to. I leave it nevertheless for the record.

There are certainly security elements to take into account writing this redirect page (as with other exposed pages) though.

---

When you allow a page redirect you basically put your reputation at stake. Someone seeing `http://myserver.mycompany.com/whatevercomeshere` expects `whatevercomeshere` to be trusted.

How to do that is introduced in the [OWASP Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet).

> Simply avoid using redirects and forwards.
>
> If used, do not allow the url as user input for the destination. This
>   can usually be done. In this case, you should have a method to
>   validate URL.
>
> If user input can’t be avoided, ensure that the supplied value is
>   valid, appropriate for the application, and is authorized for the
>   user.
>
> It is recommended that any such destination input be mapped to a
>   value, rather than the actual URL or portion of the URL, and that
>   server side code translate this value to the target URL.
>
> Sanitize input by creating a list of trusted URL's (lists of hosts or
>   a regex). Force all redirects to first go through a page notifying
>   users that they are going off of your site, and have them click a link
>   to confirm.

Comment: Thanks very much. Adjunct question. If the supplying service provides an option to use `localhost`, is that a more secure option?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Redirecting to `localhost` means that there is a service running on the computer of the user accessing the service. This is possible if this is not a pure web based service but also involves the installation of a local executable - but not very common.

Comment: Right. I'm incorporating a ride-sharing service (Uber) into my own app. I'm working through their authentication setup. I'll add to my question to explain a part of their authentication process.

Comment: Well, your addition changes quite a lot. You will not be writing redirect pages but use oAuth - which is a completely different matter. You do not need to write redirect pages in the OWASP meaning (what I linked to). You need to implement oAuth (see https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication) and just consume the authentication tokens received during the oAuth process (this is what is meant by "redirect" in https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-two-receive-redirect